# How to end phone call in C# CF?

Tags: c#, compact-framework

Microsoft website gives an example how to place a call in C# compact framework, but I don't find example how to end a phone call.

Does anybody know?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try issuing an End Key press in your cell phone. Here is a thread that might help you:

http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.tapi/browse_thread/thread/ac100a218c422a5e

Comment: thanks for ur reply.  my device does not have End key or hangup key, but it can support phone feature.  From the link, it seems that I have to create application to monitor the phone call, but I prefer not to do that.  I just want to execute my program at any time and to end the call at any time.